# Regex.Match and noncapturing groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can anyone explain why Regex.Match captures noncapturing groups. Can't find anything about it in MSDN. Why

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex("(?:a)");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match("aa");
while (matchResults.Success)
{
    foreach (Capture g in matchResults.Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
    }
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

produces output

```
a
a
```

instead of empty one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Captures is different than groups.

```
matchResults.Groups[0]
```

is always the whole match. So your group would have been

```
matchResults.Groups[1],
```

if the regex were `"(a)"`. Now since it's `"(?:a)"`, you can check that it's empty.

Captures are a separate thing - they allow you to do something like this:

If you have the regex `"(.)+"`, then it would match the string `"abc"`.

Group[1] then would be "c", because that is the last group, while

1. Groups[1].Captures[0] is "a"
2. Groups[1].Captures[1] is "b"
3. Groups[1].Captures[2] is "c".

Comment: Thanks - in such case MSDN is a bit misleading "Gets a collection of all the captures matched by the capturing group" - AFAIK in REGEX world capturing group is called exactly (a) construction